# Row dont want adding more tables in mysql because timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, timestamp, mysql-error-1067

i want to add tables in mysql row to ps_product_shop(code down) but still say error: #1067 - Invalid default value for 'available_date' . I checked docs but i dont know what i must doing. thx for reply.

```
ALTER TABLE `ps_product_shop`  ADD `NOVINKA` TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'  AFTER `on_sale`,  ADD `DOPRODEJ` TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'  AFTER `NOVINKA`,  ADD `AKCE` TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'  AFTER `DOPRODEJ`,  ADD `DOPORUCUJEME` TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'  AFTER `AKCE`,  ADD `SLEVA` TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'  AFTER `DOPORUCUJEME`,  ADD `PRIPRAVUJEME` TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'  AFTER `SLEVA`;
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the Alter query you tried to execute? I don't see an `available_date` column which would trigger the error message you described.

Comment: I would suggest to alter columns one column at a time. This will help you to debug easily

Comment: Looks like you are defining VARCHAR values as the default for an Integer column (`'0'`instead of `0`)

Answer (score 0):

You can specify `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as the default for a TIMESTAMP column(available_date).